# Return to Last Opened Activity if the App Re-open with Some Condition

Tags: java, android, android-activity, random, sharedpreferences

I have a few interesting question here about how to return to latest activity if the game was restart/re-open because I have a new game button and continue button.So when continue button clicked it will return to last activity that opened before and the condition is activity is random from activityone to activityfive

I will explain with my code

this is menu.class

```
public class menu extends Activity {

int level;

Button newgame, continues, continuelocked;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);

    continuelocked=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttoncontinuelocked);

    continues=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttoncontinue);

    newgame=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonnewgame);
    newgame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            Intent i =new Intent(menu.this, intro.class);
            startActivity(i);          
            }             
      });
}           

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

       SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("SavedGame", MODE_PRIVATE); 
       level = pref.getInt("Level", 0); 

       if(level == 0)

        {   
           continuelocked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           continues.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }   

       if(level == 1)

        {   
           continuelocked.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           continues.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }          

           SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
           editor.putInt("Level", level);
           editor.commit();

           continues=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttoncontinue);
           continues.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){

         //How to set this method to return to latest activity that i play before
         //if i use random levelactivity?

              });
    }

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

and in intro.class I do this method to make activity random,
check my code below here -

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub            

    button5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
    if(v==button5) {

        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("SavedGame", MODE_PRIVATE); 
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();      
        editor.putInt("Level", 1);  
        editor.commit();                     

     // Here, we are generating a random number
     Random generator = new Random();
     int number = generator.nextInt(5) + 1; 
     // The '5' is the number of activities

     Class activity = null;

     // Here, we are checking to see what the output of the random was
     switch(number) { 
         case 1:
             // E.g., if the output is 1, the activity we will open is ActivityOne.class
             activity = ActivityOne.class;
             break;
         case 2:
             activity = ActivityTwo.class;
             break;
         case 3:
             activity = ActivityThree.class;
             break;
         case 4:
             activity = ActivityFour.class;
             break;
         default:
             activity = ActivityFive.class;
             break;
     }
     // We use intents to start activities
     Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), activity);
     startActivity(intent);
   }
```

and in every Activity "One to Five" I put the same random activity code

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Here, we are generating a random number
        Random generator = new Random();
        int number = generator.nextInt(5) + 1; 
        // The '5' is the number of activities

    Class activity = null;

    // Here, we are checking to see what the output of the random was
    switch(number) { 
        case 1:
            // E.g., if the output is 1, the activity we will open is ActivityOne.class
            activity = ActivityOne.class;
            break;
        case 2:
            activity = ActivityTwo.class;
            break;
        case 3:
            activity = ActivityThree.class;
            break;
        case 4:
            activity = ActivityFour.class;
            break;
        default:
            activity = ActivityFive.class;
            break;
    }
    // We use intents to start activities
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), activity);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

So My question is

***First. How to open the last Activity with a Continue button if Activity was Random?***

***Second. if in every Activity had a same Random code to One until Five, How to set Disabled to Activity that already Opened before?***

Anyone can explain about this?

UPDATED

I have found a solution with my second answer, but i dont try it yet so i dont know it work or not

so i changed the code like this

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub            

    button5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
    if(v==button5) {

        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("SavedGame", MODE_PRIVATE); 
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();      
        editor.putInt("Level", 1);  
        editor.commit();

     layout7.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     layout7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

     // Here, we are generating a random number
     Random generator = new Random();
     number = generator.nextInt(5) + 1; 
     // The '5' is the number of activities

     Class activity = null;

     // Here, we are checking to see what the output of the random was
     switch(number) { 
     // E.g., if the output is 1, the activity we will open is ActivityOne.class

         case 1: if(one == 1){
             activity = ActivityOne.class;
             }
            else if(one == 2){
                Random generatorone = new Random();
                number = generatorone.nextInt(5) + 1; 
            }
             break;
         case 2: if(two== 1){
             activity = ActivityTwo.class;
             }
            else if(two== 2){
                Random generatortwo = new Random();
                number = generatortwo.nextInt(5) + 1; 
            }
             break;
         case 3:if(three== 1){
             activity = ActivityThree.class;
             }
            else if(three== 2){
                Random generatorthree = new Random();
                number = generatorthree.nextInt(5) + 1; 
            }
             break;
         case 4:if(four == 1){
             activity = ActivityFour.class;
             }
            else if(four == 2){
                Random generatorFour = new Random();
                number = generatorFour.nextInt(5) + 1; 
            }
             break;
         default:if(five== 1){
             activity = ActivityFive.class;
             }
            else if(five== 2){
                Random generatorfive = new Random();
                number = generatorfive.nextInt(5) + 1; 
            }
             break;
     }
     // We use intents to start activities
     Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), activity);
     startActivity(intent);
   }
 };
```

i think, if the int was show ==2 its mean the Activity was already opened before. so it will random again till found activity with ==1

can anyone correct my code above? it is right or not?

and my first question still dont have an answer

***First. How to open the last Activity with a Continue button if Activity was Random and the app was re-open/restart?***

Thank you in advance, have a good day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, once you open your random `Activity` you can use [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to store an ID for that `Activity`, and once you press your *continue* button, you can read this preferences, get this ID, and open the respective `Activity`.

For example, create an utility class to handle the `SharedPreferences`.

```
public class ActivityManager {

    private static ActivityManager instance = null;

    private SharedPreferences sharedPref;

    private Context context_;

    private final String prefName = "preferencesHandler";

    public static ActivityManager getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ActivityManager(context);
        }

        return instance;
    }

    private ActivityManager(Context context) {
        context_ = context;
        sharedPref = context_.getSharedPreferences(prefName,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public void saveActivity(int ID) {
        editor = sharedPref.edit();
        // Key,Value
        editor.putInt("activity_id",ID);

        editor.commit();
    }

    public int getActivityID() {
        // Key, Default Value
        return sharedPref.getInt("activity_id",0);
    }
}
```

And once you open each one of your random `Activity`, set some ID to them and save it using the class above. Then when needed, retrieve that value with `getActivityID()`. That should do the trick.

For more info on how to use `SharedPreferences`, please read [this link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html).

---

**EDIT:** On your specific case, there's this part of your code:

```
// Here, we are checking to see what the output of the random was
switch(number) { 
    case 1:
        // E.g., if the output is 1, the activity we will open is ActivityOne.class
        activity = ActivityOne.class;
        break;
    case 2:
        activity = ActivityTwo.class;
        break;
    case 3:
        activity = ActivityThree.class;
        break;
    case 4:
        activity = ActivityFour.class;
        break;
    default:
        activity = ActivityFive.class;
        break;
}
```

You can easily use that `number` variable as an ID. So, once you randomly get that number, you can also save it using the `SharedPreferences`. And when you press the *continue* `Button`, simply read that value and use a `switch-case` again to get the correct `Activity`.

Comment: oh okay i got it, but i still strange with set ID to activity can you give example of this ID Mauker?

Comment: Done. Try that ideia @Chairizky

Comment: So this "number" should i use a static int or just int to it Mauker?

Comment: Just an `int`. This number will be saved on a `key-value` xml file, and retrieved later by the `SharedPreferences`. There's no need to make it static ;)

Comment: Okay Mauker Thanks for your help :D